# SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio debugging: How to break at an exception?

Tags: sql-server-2008, debugging, ssms

In Visual Studio 2008 I can use CTRL+D+E to make selections to have the debugger break at the point of exception, regardless of whether there is a catch block or not.

[image]

Is there a similar option in SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio where the stored procedure execution will break at the point an error is thrown?

Answer (score 0):

use try and catch in transactions. for example:

```
create proc procexmaple (@parameter int)
as
    begin try
        begin transaction
            select  * from Employees where LastName = @parameter --this is an error converting nvarchar to int
        commit transaction
    end try

    begin catch
        select  * from [Orders] where OrderID = @parameter -- the catch will work and this will run
        rollback
    end catch
go
```

you can also see how to use raiserror if you want to build an error of your own:

https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-stored-procedures/sql-server-raiserror/